# ¿Qué significan las letras que aparecen al ejecutar algunos test?

Tags: phpunit

Al ejecutar ciertos test aparecen unas letras mayúsculas, justo después de los  del comienzo de la siguiente línea a la que indica la versión de PHPUnit y el autor. Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta captura en concreto es de una ejecución en la que se salta uno de los test, porque introduje una anotación `@requires extension mail` para que no falle en *Windows*.

Si se ejecutan los test en verde, no aparecen estas letras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí, haciendo que un test falle (eliminando la anotación del primer ejemplo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que hay un listado de las letras y su significado en alguna parte de la documentación de PHPUnit pero no logro encontrarlas...

Answer (score 0):

El significado esta detallado en la misma respuesta del test.
Las letras identifican el tipo de error o inconveniente.

Por ejemplo en la primera captura la "S" en celeste significa "Skipped" y está escrito en el resultado final (lo que está en amarillo). Esto quiere decir que por alguna razón un metodo no se ha completado, quizá esta marcado como test incompleto o aun no finalizado y te avisa eso, seria como un warning por decirlo de alguna forma.

Y en la ultima captura la "E" en rojo significa "Error" y está escrito en el resultado final (lo que está en rojo), e incluso te explica donde estuvo el error y cual fue. En este caso fue que no se pudo conectar al servidor de mail. Ademas te proporciona la linea exacta en donde se produjo el error.

Comment: Hola, si esas están claras, pero he visto letras menos habituales en test que me estaban fallando sin que apareciera nunca un mensaje final, se quedaban en ejecución permanente, teniendo que forzar la salida para recuperar el control de la consola. Lo que me preguntaba entonces es si habia algun listado detallado de todas esas letras y sus significados ya que en la documentación de **phpunit** encontré sólo algunas referencias aquí y allá. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Lo que yo suelo hacer es cuando estoy trabajando en un test en especial ejecuto solo ese test y cuando todo esta funcionando ejecuto completo para ir asegurandome de que todo siga funcionando bien. De esta manera cuando el proyecto se va haciendo mas grande no se me complica. Pero todo es cuestion de tecnica de cada uno. Suerte! y de nada!